# Get ajax success and hide form while loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do an ajax registration, the following works good, it gets the data from a php function I wrote somewhere else and the registration and messages for both error and success work. But I am basically looking at:

1. hiding the form once the submit button is pressed
2. display a rotating icon,
3. then if success get a success message and no form
4. otherwise display an error.

Code:

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>';
jQuery('#register-me').on('click',function(){
   var action = 'register_action';
   var username = jQuery("#st-username").val();
   var mail_id = jQuery("#st-email").val();
   var firname = jQuery("#st-fname").val();
   var lasname = jQuery("#st-lname").val();
   var passwrd = jQuery("#st-psw").val();
   var ajaxdata = {
      action: 'register_action',
      username: username,
      mail_id: mail_id,
      firname: firname,
      lasname: lasname,
      passwrd: passwrd,
   }
   jQuery.post( ajaxurl, ajaxdata, function(res){
       jQuery("#error-message").html(res);
});
```

Comment: That last comma in `passwrd: passwrd,` at the end of that object will cause issues in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Add id="myform" to the form element, then:
$("#myform").hide();

About the icon. When you click the button you could make the icon visible and when succeed or error then hide again.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#register-me').on('click',function(){
    $("#myform").hide();
    jQuery('#loadingmessage').show(); 
    var action = 'register_action';
    var username = jQuery("#st-username").val();
    var mail_id = jQuery("#st-email").val();
    var firname = jQuery("#st-fname").val();
    var lasname = jQuery("#st-lname").val();
    var passwrd = jQuery("#st-psw").val();
    var ajaxdata = {
        action: 'register_action',
        username: username,
        mail_id: mail_id,
        firname: firname,
        lasname: lasname,
        passwrd: passwrd,
    }
    jQuery.post( ajaxurl, ajaxdata, function(res){
        $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message
        $("#myform").show();
        jQuery("#error-message").html(res);
    });
});
```

An id to the form, and add a div with an image, give it an id and hide it with css.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the deferred options here:

```
jQuery('#register-me').on('click', function () {
    var action = 'register_action';
    var username = jQuery("#st-username").val();
    var mail_id = jQuery("#st-email").val();
    var firname = jQuery("#st-fname").val();
    var lasname = jQuery("#st-lname").val();
    var passwrd = jQuery("#st-psw").val();
    var ajaxdata = {
        action: 'register_action',
        username: username,
        mail_id: mail_id,
        firname: firname,
        lasname: lasname,
        passwrd: passwrd
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, ajaxdata)
        .beforeSend(function (data, textSttus, jqxhr) {
        $('#myform').hide();
        alert('Show the spinner');
        $('#spinner').show();
    })
        .done(function (data, jqxhr, settings ) {
        alert("success");
    })
        .fail(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        alert("oops, fail");
        $('#myform').show();
    })
        .always(function (event, jqxhr, settings ) {
        alert('hide the spinner please');
        $('#spinner').hide();
    });
});
```